# Mysql count and return just one row of data

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery, having

I need to count the amount of users that have have answered all of those 3 profile_options (so they have at least 3 records in the profile_answers table).

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(users.id)) users_count
FROM users
INNER JOIN profile_answers ON profile_answers.user_id = users.id
WHERE profile_answers.profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(profile_answers.id))>=3
```

The problem is that this query is return a table with rows for each user and how many they answered (in this case always 3). What I need is to return just one row that has the total number of users (so the sum of all rows of this example)

I know how to do it with another subquery but the problem is that I am running into "Mysql::Error: Too high level of nesting for select"

Is there a way to do this without the extra subquery?

```
SELECT SUM(sum_sub.users_count) FROM (
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(users.id)) users_count
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN profile_answers ON profile_answers.user_id = users.id
 WHERE profile_answers.profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
 GROUP BY users.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(profile_answers.id))>=3)
) sum_sub
```

Comment: Could you please post your table definitions as well as a sample of the data you're working with?

Comment: If I understand the query correctly you should not need to use sum. Select only COUNT(DISTINCT(users.id)) form your sub query should give you what you need

Comment: It retruns multiple rows one for each user. I need just one row with the amount of users that match the conditions.

Comment: @AntoniosChrysakis give my updated answer another try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this query a shoot

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(u.id)) AS users_count 
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) AS total
     FROM profile_answers
     WHERE profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
     GROUP BY users.id 
     HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) = 3
) AS a ON a.user_id = u.id
```

If you have lots of data in your tables, you will get a better/faster performance by using temporary tables like so

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) AS total
FROM profile_answers
WHERE profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
GROUP BY users.id 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) = 3;
```

Then your final query will look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(u.id)) as users_count 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN on a.user_id = u.id
```

Unless there is a need to join the `users` table you can go with this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS users_count
FROM (
     SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) AS total
     FROM profile_answers
     WHERE profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
     GROUP BY users.id 
     HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT profile_option_id) = 3
) AS a
```

Should you need another solution, please consider providing us you `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for the query and the table definitions along with a better problem description.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I still have issues with you solution. Since the example is only part of a bigger query mysql is complaining for to many levels of select. I need to do this without another select in the joined table or anywhere else.

Comment: MySQL will complicate it because the optimizer does not do a good job with aggregated sub queries. What you can do is create a temporary table of the memory engine with the user_id as a key and they join the putter query to the temp table

Answer (score 0):

You can give the queries a name using the AS clause. See the updated query below.

```
SELECT SUM(sum_sub.users_count) FROM (
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(users.id)) as users_count
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN profile_answers ON profile_answers.user_id = users.id
 WHERE profile_answers.profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
 GROUP BY users.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(profile_answers.id))>=3)
) as sum_sub
```

Comment: Hi akshar I am not sure what changed from mine? I can't use this as mysql is complaining for too many levels of select

Comment: when naming queries or tables from what they are originally, you have to use the AS clause. I had added the "as" for sum_sub and users_count. But looks like that wasn't an issue. A lesson for me then.

Answer (score 0):

You should not group by on a field not present in select statement.

`select id, count(*) from users group by id` is fine

`select count(id) from users group by id` is NOT

Regarding your query I think the link to user table is not necessary. Just using foreign key should be fine.

Try this one:

```
select count(*) from 
(SELECT users_id count(*) as cnt
FROM profile_answers
INNER JOIN users ON profile_answers.user_id = users.id
WHERE profile_answers.profile_option_id IN (37,86,102) 
group by users_id
having count(*) >3)
```

Comment: Hi it's required as this is not the whole query only the part that is not working I am adding some dynamic conditions in there that require the user table.